# Gamesparks: Remove player from pending match

Tags: unity-game-engine, gamesparks

I'm using gamesparks and I need to disconnect player from pendingMatch, if the player is waiting for another player to connect very long time. Found [this](https://docs.gamesparks.com/api-documentation/cloud-code-api/multiplayer/sparkmatch.html): `match.removePlayersById(playerIdsToRemove)` but I need to have `matchID`, to get `match`. but don't know how.

Please help me to remove player from match.

thank, you

Answer (score 0):

Use `Spark.getMultiplayer().cancelMatchmaking(player, matchShortCode, matchGroup);`  `matchShortCode` you can get from SparkData and in case you don't have `matchGroup` use empty string.